# Events is not being consumed by events

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'm trying to understand raising and consuming events in C#.

I can't consume the events which I raised.

Could you please take a look at my code? Thanks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var evtClass = new EventClass();
        evtClass.OnVariableLoaded(new EventClass.CustomEventArgs("test"));ded;
    }

    static void c_VariableLoaded(object sender, EventClass.CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        // The event is not being executed...
    }
}
public class EventClass
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> VariableLoaded;

    protected virtual void OnVariableLoaded(CustomEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        VariableLoaded?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
    }

    public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CustomEventArgs(string variable1)
        {
            Variable1 = variable1;
        }

        public string Variable1 { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody is calling OnVariableLoaded?

Comment: @Luca How can I call OnVariableLoaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you just subscribe to event with

```
evtClass.VariableLoaded += c_VariableLoaded;
```

But there is no call to this event. Something must call it from the evtClass, for your event handler in main to work out.

Consider looking, for instance, to Windows Forms events. You are subscribing to Button Click event with some event handler - like in your main. But you must press the button to run handler's code.

So it is in your code - you subscribed to event, but the event itself is never raised. To raise it from your code, you should call  `OnVariableLoaded` with some args you construct.

Consider looking for some examples of events - for instance, progress bar update, or PropertyChanged pattern.

Comment: I have updated my code, but I still do not know how to consume events.